# How can I select the first link in my menu without selecting the other links inside the dropdown?

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors

I'm having trouble figuring out how to solve this CSS problem.

The code is create by a WordPress plugin so have limited possibilities when it comes to naming the classes and so on.

This is the code:

```
<li class="page_item page-item-365 page_item_has_children current_page_item has_children”>
    <a href="http://www.xxx.dk/side1/side2/“>Side 2</a>
    <ul class="children">
        <li class="page_item page-item-556”>
            <a href="http://www.xxx.dk/“>punkt 1</a>
        </li>   
        <li class="page_item page-item-556”>
            <a href="http://www.xxx.dk/“>punkt 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-556”>
            <a href="http://www.xxx.dk/“>punkt 1</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

The problem is that all of my links become bold when I'm styling them. I only want it to happen on the current page (selected page). I have tried with the following CSS code, but without luck:

```
li.current_page_item a:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe I found a solution - dont know if I understand it but it works ;)

```
.current_page_item > a {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: This is the `>` direct child selector. This only selects `<a>` elements that are the *direct child* of their parent, the `.current_page_item` in this case. Because the other `<a>` tags have other `<li>` items as parents, these don't get selected.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, every a is the first child of a li.
What you are searching for is:

```
li.current_page_item a {
```

**Furthermore** all of your menu entries link to the same id. So I guess every of it get the "current" class, if one is selected. Add some other links to the menu and you will see, that it will work!

Comment: Martin - can you tell me what difference is between the solution I found and the one from you? Just so I hopefully learn something :)

Comment: This would also affect all `<a>` inside of the nested `<ul>`

Answer (score 0):

You were close to the solution ;-) 
Have a look here, is this what you looking for?

```
li.current_page_item > a:first-child {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Example on Codepen:
http://codepen.io/funkysoul/pen/XNVdbE

Comment: Ok - it worked with     `.current_page_item > a {
    font-weight: bold;
}` I guess it is kind of the same? @funkysoulzh

Comment: Yes, except this one's more specific. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: It's basically the same yep!

Answer (score 0):

please recheck your code. refer the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: The code was created by a wordpress plugin, so I cant do anything about that - at least not with my coding knowledge.